# Show row-wise column value as well as the same column's aggregate using group by in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have some data that looks like this:

```
students:

    id  score  section    ...
    --------------------------------------------
    1   85     A        ...
    2   40     A        ...
    3   61     B        ...
    4   71     B        ...
    5   80     B        ...
```

I would like to show the score each student along with the maximum score of their section.

```
students:

    id  score  section  section_max_score  ...
    --------------------------------------------
    1   85     A        85                 ...
    2   40     A        85                 ...
    3   61     B        80                 ...
    4   71     B        80                 ...
    5   80     B        80                 ...
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
select id, score, section, max(score) as section_max_score from students group by section;
```

This gives an error that I need to include other columns in the group by.

```
select id, score, section, max(score) as section_max_score from students group by section, score, id;
```

This just shows the individual score of each student instead of the section maximum.

What am I missing and how do I fix it?

Essentially, I need to be able to use a particular column as well an aggregate on that column in a group by query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window function `max()` :

```
select id, score, section, max(score) over ( partition by section) as section_max_score 
from students
```

Or use an `inner join` to join your table to a dataset of maximum score per section:

```
select s.*, t.section_max_score
  from students s
  inner join (
    select section, max(score) as section_max_score
    from students
    group by section
) as t on s.section = t.section
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DEIMMbKY)